# Generate a random number with regex on Yahoo Pipes?

Tags: regex, yahoo, yahoo-pipes

I want to replace the item title of an RSS feed on Yahoo Pipes with a random number but can't find out how to do it?

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the fetch_page module and a little regex to extract a random number from a lotto generator page.
http://www.lottonumbers.net/uk-daily-play-number-generator.asp

**Ammendum:** As of April 2012 the basic 'Fetch page' module has been depreciated and replaced with
 'XPATH Fetch Page', same principle but slightly different syntax for defining content to be extracted.